# Make the <telerik:RadDropDownList> as ReadOnly

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, telerik, c#-3.0

I am trying to make/set the telerik controls to read only, so no one will be able to edit the values.

I have searched and tried different solutions but none of them seems to work for me.

I have tried making the following solution, the telerik drop down list ui code is:

```
<telerik:RadDropDownList ID="rddPrefix" runat="server" width="100%" DropDownHeight="200"> </telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

and applying the javascript below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var dropdownlist = $("#rddPrefix");
   dropdownlist.readonly();
</script>
```

Please provide some appropriate solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach to achieve this requirement:

```
<telerik:RadDropDownList ... OnClientDropDownOpening="preventComboAction"
    OnClientItemSelecting="preventComboAction">

<script>
function preventComboAction(sender, args) {
    args.set_cancel(true);
}
</script>
```